# Is it possible to do this integral with contour integration?

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm wondering if it's possible to do this integral with contour integration: $$\int_0^\infty dr \frac{r\cos(ar)}{(r^2+1)(1+2\sqrt{r^2+1})^2}. $$
Having integrated this numerically, I'm sure this integral converges. I thought of computing this as the real part and changing $\cos(ar)$ to $\text{Re}(e^{iar})$, but then I'm not sure about what to do about the poles and branch points. I was thinking of using the branch cut $(-\infty,-i]\cup[i,\infty)$ and use a semicircle contour in the upper-half plane which avoids the top branch cut. But then since the integrand is odd, I'm wondering how to deal with the $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$ sections along the real line canceling out. Maybe I'm supposed to compute it with one side picking up a phase from the branch cut?

Comment: I'm guessing it should be $\cos(ar)$ in the integrand, is it?

Comment: @JoanS.GuillametF. Yes, I have edited the post.

Comment: It obviously converges, as the tail drops off with $r^{-3}$. Since it is not helpful to extend the integral to $-\infty$, your next choice is the find another route out from $0$ to $\infty$ that you can integrate. That is, is there some curve $\gamma : [0, \infty) \to \Bbb C$ with $\gamma(0) = 0$ and $ |\gamma(t)| \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$ such that setting $r = \gamma(t)$ in the integral gives you something you can integrate with respect to $t$. If so, this integral will be the opposite of that integral, plus any included residues.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes, that's true. I'm not sure if such an integral exists though, since I can only think of doing some semicircle-shaped contour and I think there would be a problem with the function being odd.

Comment: To use contour integration for this, you need a family of closed contours such that in a limit (1) part of the contour becomes $[0,\infty)$, (2) part of the contour becomes an integral you can calculate by some other means, (3) the integral over the remainder of the contour goes to $0$. Since the integrand drops off with $\frac 1{r^2}$, the integral over the unbounded part of the contour will go to $0$ as long as its length is bounded by $r^2$, which is easy to do. Thus the hard part is (2). Since the integrand is odd, using $(-\infty, 0]$ doesn't work. So you HAVE to find a different route.

Comment: There is one more need I should have mentioned: The integrand must be analytic inside other than isolated singularities, so in this case, you need a branch cut of $\sqrt{1 + z^2}$ that lies entirely outside the contour. However, my point is you have only two choices: Either find such an integrable route to complex $\infty$ other than $[0,\infty)$ or $(-\infty, 0]$, or else give up on doing this by contour integration. If such a route does not exist, this cannot be done by the method of residues.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Well, it depends on what you mean by "done by the method of residues". Maybe a second method will restate it as an integral we can evaluate with the residue theorem. For example, the parity concern can be addressed by differentiation under the integral sign, but it could still mean most of the work was done with the residue theorem.

Comment: @J.G. - Doh! That is an excellent idea. Loses a power of $r$ in the denominator, but decreasing as $\frac 1{r^2}$ is still sufficient.